# How can we extract specific test from the text in python

Tags: python

I have output of a function called ABC like below as a string:

```
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:  --incremental append
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --check-column DTIN
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --last-value 2019-07-27 00:00:00.0
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: (Consider saving this with 'sqoop job --create')
```

How can i get `--last-value` in python ,`2019-07-27 00:00:00.0` will be dynamic .

Note: I have around 100 lines of data as output but here i given only last 4 rows.

expected `--last-value = 2019-07-27 00:00:00.0`
here date is dynamic based on output.

Comment: why not have a regex to match date of the format you want?

Comment: I have another date in the output so I cant use regex to match the date

Comment: Both the date are of different format. One is 19/09/09 and other is 2019-07-27.

Comment: dates are same format

Comment: Is not clear if you have one or more occurrences of `--last-value` in your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string slice or regular expression to get this date from input.

1. String slice:

   ```
   text = """19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --incremental append
   19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --check-column DTIN
   19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --last-value 2019-07-27 00:00:00.0
   19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: (Consider saving this with 'sqoop job --create')"""

   keyword = "--last-value"
   idx = text.index(keyword) + len(keyword) + 1  # keyword index + length of keyword + 1 (space)
   last_value = text[idx: text.index("\n", idx)]
   ```
2. [Regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/nHsvv1/1):

   ```
   import re

   last_value = re.search(r"--last-value (.+)\n", text).group(1)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Regex are your best friend!

If there are many occurrences of '--last-value' in your file, you must use `re.findall()` instead `re.search()` to get all values, as in the following code:

```
import re 
text = """19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --incremental append
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --check-column DTIN
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --last-value 2019-07-27 00:00:01.0
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: --last-value 2029-07-27 00:00:02.0
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: (Consider saving this with 'sqoop job --create')"""

sep = '--last-value '
regex = "%s(.+)\n" % sep

string_dates = re.findall(regex, text)
print(string_dates) # ['2019-07-27 00:00:01.0', '2029-07-27 00:00:02.0']
```

It can be useful to convert strings in the `string_dates` list to`datetime` according to your format:

```
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
datetime_values = [dt.strptime(res, date_format) for res in string_dates]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a [primitive RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/1Ff0Kd/1). You can use it to get the related lines from your log.

**Code:**

```
import re
data = """19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:  --incremental append
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --check-column DTIN
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --last-value 2019-07-27 00:00:00.0
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: (Consider saving this with 'sqoop job --create')
19/09/09 10:34:37 INFO tool.ImportTool:   --last-value 2019-08-08 04:02:99.2
"""

last_values = re.findall(r"--last-value [0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]", data)
print(last_values)
```

Output:

```
>>> python3 test.py 
['--last-value 2019-07-27 00:00:00.0', '--last-value 2019-08-08 04:02:99.2']
```